# Php script issue with explode function

Tags: php

I have a website that splits my long tail keywords into many small ones, like this for example:

I have a desired keyword which I want to look like this:

`fishing is relaxing`

But I get instead of that, I get:

`fishing,is,relaxing`

I don't know much about PHP but I think its a explode thing in function script

```
function get_popular_tags()
{
    global $conn;

    $tags       = array();
    $sql        = "SELECT keyword FROM video ORDER BY viewnumber LIMIT 10";
    $rs         = $conn->execute($sql);
    $rows       = $rs->getrows();
    foreach ( $rows as $row )
    {
        $tag_arr = explode(' ', $row['"keyword"']);
        foreach ( $tag_arr as $tag )
        {
            if ( strlen($tag) > 3 && !in_array($tag, $tags) )
            {
                $tags[] = $tag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your string is "fishing is relaxing" than your expected output?

Comment: Not sure about the extra quotes in `$row['"keyword"']`

Comment: So don’t explode it then, remove the inner foreach loop, and add `$row['keyword']` to the $tags array directly instead …

Comment: let me know about your output?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply guys, when i enter the keyword "fishing is relaxing" no quotes, i get this fishing,is,relaxing and i want "fishing is relaxing"

Comment: Nigel i added those quote marks by mistake, you are right, this is the full script full original https://pastebin.com/vhakJWXq

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your function except quotes. I think you are getting `fishing,is,relaxing` somewhere else. Because according to your logic tags array must contain just "fishing" and "relaxing" like this:

```
[0] => 'fishing'
[1] => 'relaxing'
```

One more thing is that it is an array but you are showing your data in a string form which is not possible until you not use `implode(',', $tags);`

Comment: I am getting what you said, fishing,is, relaxing but i want to have fishing is relaxing can you tell me what i need to change in the script to get that please.

Comment: @JohnHanson I think you want to say the $row['keyword'] contains "fishing, is, relaxing" ? Am I right? This is not clear because you can see in your question comments that people understood that $row['keyword'] contains "fishing is relaxing" and after loop iterartion you want some other value.

Comment: if $row['keyword'] contains "fishing, is, relaxing" then in your video table keyword column contains string in this format. Can you share your video table screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11935532/maryam-aslam Thanks for the reply you are right my keyword looks like "fishing,is,relaxing" and i want to have  "fishing is relaxing" , now please tell me what is a video table and where i can find it in order to post it.

Comment: @JohnHanson You are using which database? Whatever database you are using if you are using PHPMyAdmin tool go in video table, export it, it will generate video.sql and if you are using some other management tool then it is also fine because in every tool there is a "export" option.